# choosing a programmable thermostat: wiring and power

Tags: wiring, thermostat, power

I want to replace my non-programmable RobertShaw 9500 thermostat with a programmable thermostat.

The current wiring uses these terminals:  RH, W, Y, G.

With that set of wires, can I get a wire-powered thermostat with battery backup, or does it has to be battery only?

Comment: See the questions tagged [tag:thermostat-c-wire]

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get a "wire powered" thermostat, without at least one more wire. You'll need an additional wire, to connect to the `C` terminal of the new thermostat.